# iAD doesn't show on 3.5" screen?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios-simulator, iad

I built my app for a 4" screen. In order for everything to show up on a 3.5" screen I checked the option *Use Autolayout*.

I have a iAD Banner view at the bottom of my 4" Storyboard screen. Whether or not I check the *Use Autolayout* button, the Ad doesn't show up when I run my app on 3.5" simulator.

If I move my banner view up so it shows on the 3.5" it also moves it up on the 4" simulator.
How do I get it so the iAD shows at the bottom of both 3.5" and 4" screens and hopefully with the AutoLayout still checked which saves me a lot of time.

Comment: set constraints for iAd

Comment: could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

set constraints on your iAd banner

[image]

Comment: Im new to Xcode and I don't really know what constraints are. Could you please tell me what they should be set to or how do I find out?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html understand this link

Comment: ok so can you tell me which restraint I need to set to make it always touch the bottom. I was going to try Bottom Edges in the alignment constraints but it wouldn't let me check the box.

Comment: set constraints on your iAd view

Comment: can you tell me what to do because I can't figure it out. I want my ad to be at the bottom for 3.5" and 4"

Comment: I already have my ad... What constraint do I set so it is always at the bottom of the screen for both screen siZes?